# Laravel pass object to view

Tags: laravel-5

When I'm trying to pass an object through a view with the AppServiceProvider it gives an error an says

> Trying to get property of non-object

This is currently my App\Providers:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Auth;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $users = Auth::user();
        view()->share('user','users');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And when I say in the view:

```
{!! user->name !!}
```

It throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the '$' on users when passing the variable to view. So it can't be rendered on the view.
it must be:

```
$users = Auth::user();
view()->share('user', $users);
```

Comment: @jamie — it should. Passing `'users'` doesn't pass an object, it passes a string.

Comment: Maybe also try using `{!! $user->name !!}` in the view?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it looks like when I'm saying $user = Auth::user(); the object is empty? Because I receive the error: Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\resources\views\tickets\index.blade.php)

Comment: In the view I'm saying {!! $name->name !!}

Comment: But I will post this as a new question.